# Javascript D3.js Nested Axis Labels for Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radar-chart

I would like to add nested axis Labels to my radar chart. All online resources just show a singular axis. 
An example of the image I am trying to reproduce is shown in the below figure.

The axis is Management.sr_lvl_1, Management.sr_lvl_2, Management.sr_lvl_3... However, I want the word management to appear only once in the label which spans across all sr_lvl

[image]